# php check if two variables are empty and merge them togheter

Tags: php

First thing first, i'm new to php.

I'm trying to check if two variables are both empty, and if so merge them togheter to display only one result, but if one of them is not empty, than i have to display is value.

I currently have:

```
$customerNotesWC = "";
$DYSPrintableOrderNotes = "test note";
```

Here's the code i tried so far:

```
function displayCustomerOrderNotes($customerNotesWC,$DYSPrintableOrderNotes){
    if ($customerNotesWC == "") {
        $customerNotesWC = "(none)";
    }
    if ($DYSPrintableOrderNotes ==""){
        $DYSPrintableOrderNotes = "(none)";
    }
    if ($DYSPrintableOrderNotes == "(none)" && $customerNotesWC == "(none)"){
        $NotesToDisplay = "(none)";
    }
    else {
        $NotesToDisplay = $customerNotesWC . "<br/>" . $DYSPrintableOrderNotes;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, as the results is the following:

```
(none)    
Pre-sale order note
```

I know that there must be a better way to achieve this, and any suggestions will be really appreciated.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get your desired functionality of only printing "(none)" when both values are blank, the simplest thing to do to fix your code is remove the code that's setting either value to "(none)" and change your main if-statement to check for "":

```
function displayCustomerOrderNotes($customerNotesWC,$DYSPrintableOrderNotes){
    if ($DYSPrintableOrderNotes == "" && $customerNotesWC == ""){
        $NotesToDisplay = "(none)";
    }
    else {
        $NotesToDisplay = $customerNotesWC . "<br/>" . $DYSPrintableOrderNotes;
    }
    //shouldn't there be an echo $NotesToDisplay; or return $NotesToDisplay; ? or something?
}
```

Comment: i just tried your answer, but it still prints "(none)". Currently i have $customerNotesWC blank and $DYSPrintableOrderNotes not blank.

Comment: Ok sorry my bad there was an error i didn't notice in my code. Just fixed it and it's now working perfectly. Thanks a lot